# Startup Window based on Properties.Default values - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms

I have to open different window based on default values.Following is code:

```
public void ChooseNextWindowBasedOnDefaultValue()
{
    if (Settings.Default["DsrType"] == null || Settings.Default["DsrType"].ToString() == "" || Settings.Default["TimeSlot"].ToString() == "")
    {
        ShowMainWindow();
    }

    else if (Settings.Default["DsrType"].ToString().ToLower() == "excel")
    {
        ShowLoadExcelWindow();
    }

    else if (Settings.Default["DsrType"].ToString().ToLower() == "texteditor")
    {
        ShowTextEditorWindow();
    }
}
```

Everything works fine in my local machine. When i install the EXE in others machine and tried to run, no window is starting. where it went wrong? i think i couldn't read Default values in others machine

Comment: Are the default values properly included in the app.config?

Comment: Yes default values includes in app.config. I have used 'User' scope default values b'coz i need to change default values at run-time. @TimothyGroote

Answer (score 0):

Add your settings to the `Properties`->`Settings.settings` file and access them using the auto-generated properties:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Properties.Settings.Default.DsrType) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Properties.Settings.Default.TimeSlot))
{
    ShowMainWindow();
}
```